# Google Analytics Campaigns Not Tracking E-Commerce

Tags: google-analytics

I am running email campaigns via MailChimp and tracking the success of my campaigns via Google Analytics. I can successfully see data being tracked for:

```
Reporting > Conversions > Ecommerce (Receiving Data)
Reporting > Traffic Sources > Campaigns (Receiving Data)
```

However, I am not receiving any Ecommerce data for the individual campaigns:

`Reporting > Traffic Sources > Campaigns > Ecommerce (No data)`

So I see data like:

`Visits: 18,501`
`Revenue: $0.00`

Everything I have read leads me to believe this should just `"work"` if Ecommerce is setup. Is there some additional action I need to take for this work?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your Analytics code which tracks the ecommerce?

Comment: Is ecommerce tracking enabled for that Analytics profile? And what shopping cart are you using? Does it support ecommerce tracking?

Answer (score 1):

after you selected your website is an Ecommerce website. You won't automatic get the ecommerce data.

You need to implement the ga.js ecommerce tracking methods in your shopping cart pages or through your ecommerce software.

You can refer here for how to 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce